# Meteor: Where exactly (full path) are ostrio:files images located on production server?

Tags: image, meteor, server, production

Well, I am trying to figure out why the images I upload from my production server occasionally disappear. It does not happen on mup stop & mup start and it does not happen when deploying... but somewhen it happens. So in order to debug, I am trying to locate the files on the server, but "locate tsFvWBvjyGjcgDivc.png" (where tsFvWBvjyGjcgDivc is from the Images collection, and currently displaying on the client) does not return anything.
Any hints on how to find the files?
Do you have an idea why and how the files are disappearing? They btw, do not get deleted from the Images collection.

a) I have no idea what storage engine I am using, it all runs on my Digitalocean server.

b) Yes, this is my constructor and debug is set to true

```
const Images = new FilesCollection({
  debug: true,
  storagePath: './images',
  permissions: 0o774,
  parentDirPermissions: 0o774,
  collectionName: 'Images',
  allowClientCode: false,
  onBeforeUpload: function (file) {
    if (file.size <= 1024 * 1024 * 10 && /png|jpe?g/i.test(file.extension)) {
      return true;
    }
    return 'Please upload image, with size equal or less than 10MB';
  }
});
```

c) console.log( process.env.NODE_ENV ) on the server returns "production"

d) This is a log of what happens when a file is missing but the client requests it:

```
[FilesCollection] [download(/cdn/storage/Images/a3DHfbmP7rWBox7aA/original/a3DHfbmP7rWBox7aA.png)] [_404] File not found
```

Comment: Some questions here: Which storage engine are you using with `ostrio:files`? Did you set a `storagePath` in the [constructor](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Constructor)? Can you please set on your `FilesCollection` the debug property to true in the constructor? What does your server log on startup when typing: `console.log( process.env.NODE_ENV )`?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have added the answers to my question :)